# How to get info from another React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have two React Native apps `A` & `B`,
app `A` have a login system, after login it stores the username,
I want `B` app to check if the username is stored in `A` app and get the username.
Is there a way to do this in React Native?

I use `React Native Async Storage` in `A` app to store username
https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `Linking` from react native.

[There is a complete blog on that.](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2018/04/04/app-app-communication-react-native-android/)

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be to look at [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) or [Shared Keychain Access](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps) on iOS. Regardless you'll need to explore platform specific options for each platform you target. React Native doesn't provide functionality for this out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your response I'm targeting Android.. I just got an idea to use deep linking for this I think it will work :)